# Recurrence relation exponential

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve recurrence relation:
$P_1=1; P_n=P_{n-1}+2^n\\$

I am completely new in this type of equations. Can somebody explain this to me? I tried myself and got something like this:

$P_n=1+1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3+...+2^n$

And I don't know if this is correct and how to continue

Comment: Correct is $$P_n=1+2^2+2^3+\cdots +2^n=2^{n+1}-3$$

Comment: Can you show how did you get this?

Comment: Beginning with $1$ , we add $2^2,2^3,2^4$ and so on. What you also need is $$1+2+2^2+\cdots +2^n=2^{n+1}-1$$ which is a well known geometric sum.

Answer (score 1):

For the homogenous solution $P_{n}-P_{n-1}=0$ you try a solution of the form $P_{n}=x^{n}$. So substituting gives $$x^{n}-x^{n-1}=x^{n-1}(x-1)=0$$

So $x=0,1$ and the homogenous solution is $P_{n}=C_{1}$.

Next we want to find a particular solution of the full recurrence $$P_{n}-P_{n-1}=2^n.$$

So we look for a solution of the form $P_{n}=k2^{n}$, for some constant $k$. So substituting into the equation gives

$$k2^{n}-k2^{n-1}=k2^{n-1}(2-1)=k2^{n-1}=2^{n}$$

Now diving both sides by $2^{n-1}$ we obtain that $k=2.$

Thus we have the solution $P_{n}=C_{1}+2^{n+1}.$

Now since we know that $P_{1}=1$ then $P_{1}=C_{1}+2^{2}=C_{1}+4=1$ so $C_{1}=-3$. Hence the general solution is $$P_{n}=2^{n+1}-3.$$

---

Iteration method.

We have $P_{n-1}=P_{n-2}+2^{n-1}$ so $P_{n}=P_{n-1}+2^{n}=P_{n-2}+2^{n-1}+2^{n}.$

Then $P_{n-2}=P_{n-3}+2^{n-2}$ which gives

$P_{n}=P_{n-2}+2^{n-1}+2^{n}=P_{n-3}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}+2^{n}$

Thus $P_{n}=P_{n-k}+2^{n-(k-1)}+2^{n-(k-2)}+...+2^{n-1}+2^{n}$

So when $n-k=1$ we have $P_{n}=P_{1}+2^{(n-k)+1}+2^{(n-k)+2}+...+2^{n-1}+2^{n}=1+2^{2}+2^{3}+....+2^{n-1}+2^n$

$=1+2^{2}(1+2+2^{2}+...+2^{n-3}+2^{n-2})$.

Now we will use that the sum of the first $n+1$ terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.) is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}ar^{k}=a(\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1})$$

Thus we obtain $$P_{n}=1+2^{2}(1+2+2^{2}+...+2^{n-3}+2^{n-2})$$
$$1+2^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k=1+2^{2}\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2-1}$$
$$=1+2^2(2^{n-1}-1)=1+2^{n-1+2}-2^{2}=2^{n+1}-3$$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Problem is that I should do this with the iteration method (Substitution method) Can you help me with in this way?

Comment: Did you arrive at $P_{n}=1+2^{2}+2^{3}+...+2^{n}$?

Comment: I am arriving at $P_n=2+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+...+2^{n}$ , I don't know where my mystake is

Comment: I've added to my answer. Hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: Yes it's clear now, thank you very much!